# requesting a flask API

Tags: python, rest, flask

Why I can't view the variable name ?

When I enter:

```
curl --data "name=value1" http://127.0.0.1:5000/echo
```

The output is :

```
ECHO : POST
```

I am expecting also:

```
value1
```

This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/echo', methods = ['POST'] )
def api_echo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "ECHO : POST\n"
        print request.args['name']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are looking for is in `request.form` not `request.args`:

```
def api_echo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "ECHO : POST\n"
        print request.form['name']
```

This prints:

```
ECHO : POST

val1
```

---

You don't return anything from the `api_echo` end point. Curl is throwing an error, despite the print statement appearing in the python logs. You should add a `return` value to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/echo', methods = ['POST'] )
def api_echo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #changing "args" to "form" did the trick
        print request.form['name']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from request.args, make the following request:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/echo?name=value1
```